# Beginner PHP: I can't insert data into MYSQL database

Tags: php, mysql

I'm learning PHP right now and I'm trying to insert data into a MySQL database called "pumpl2" The table is set up like this.

```
create table product
 ( productid int unsigned not null auto_increment primary key,
   price int(9) not null,
   value int(9) not null,
   description text
 );
```

I have a form and want to insert the fields from the form in the database. Here is what the php file looks like.

```
<?php

// create short variable names
$price = $_POST['price'];
$value = $_POST['value'];
$description = $_POST['description'];

if (!$price || !$value || !$description) {
 echo "You have not entered all the required details.<br />"
  ."Please go back and try again.";
 exit;
}

@ $db = new mysqli('localhost', 'pumpl', '********', 'pumpl2');

if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
 echo "Error: Could not connect to database. Please try again later.";
 exit;
}

$query = "insert into pumpl2 values
 ('".$price."', '".$value."', '".$description."')";
$result = $db->query($query);

if ($result) {
 echo  $db->affected_rows." product inserted into database.";
} else {
 echo "An error has occurred.  The item was not added.";
}

$db->close();

?>
```

When I submit the form, I get an error message "An error has occurred.  The item was not added."

Does anyone know what the problem is? Thank you!

Comment: You are concatenating raw post values into an INSERT statement which is a VERY bad idea.  You should look into PDO and prepared statements: http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php

Comment: @Colonel actually, PDO hold no monopoly for the parametrized queries. mysqli has similar mechanism.

Comment: Another way of formatting queries would be:
$sql = "SELECT * FROM table";  
$result = mysql_query($sql) or die("Error Occured".mysql_error());

Comment: @Col. Shrapnel: It doesn't but PDO supports multiple databases, so you only have to learn the syntax for using DBs once, then apply it regardless of which DB types you actually use.

Comment: @R. Bemrose I don't think that a few functions is a too big deal to learn.

Answer (score 4):

This should give you more information:

```
echo "An error has occurred: " . $db->error();
```

Comment: Thank you. I added this to the script. I'm sure it will help in the future.

Comment: @Victor, actually, that's wrong approach. trigger_error() should be used instead of echo. and to add a query itself to the error message would be also good idea.

Answer (score 4):

You are trying to insert into the table called `pumpl2`, but the `CREATE TABLE` statement created a table called `product`.

In addition, as [ZeissS noted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2817928/beginner-php-i-cant-insert-data-into-mysql-database/2817952#2817952), you have to consider the following:

```
CREATE TABLE product ( 
    productid int unsigned not null auto_increment primary key,
    price int(9) not null,
    value int(9) not null,
    description text
);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.09 sec)

INSERT INTO product VALUES (1, 1, 'test');
ERROR 1136 (21S01): Column count doesn't match value count at row 1
```

To solve that error, you need to explicitly specify the list of the columns:

```
INSERT INTO product (price, value, description) VALUES (1, 1, 'test');
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.03 sec)
```

Comment: Thank you. I believe this is correct. I combined this advice with advice above and it helped me fix the problem.

Comment: No, you should'nt insert NULL here, since the column is defined as `not null` and `auto_increment`. I would say, working with NULL here is beeing dependent on the underlying database too much. Make it clear (other people are not confused by the null value) and simple: Don't insert this column.

Comment: @ZeissS: Good point. Fixed. (In fact, it wouldn't have worked in strict mode.)

Answer (score 3):

You only insert three columns but have four defined in your table. Thus you have to name the columns explicitly:

```
 INSERT INTO tableName (ColumnA, ColumnB, ColumnC) VALUES ('A', 'B', 'C')
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$query = "insert into pumpl2.product (price, value, description) values('" .
         $db->read_escape_string($price) . "', '".
         $db->read_escape_string($value) . "', '" .
         $db->read_escape_string($description) . "')";
$result = $db->query($query);
```

And an obligatory `XKCD` cartoon:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Your query is wrong, you didn't have the columns specified.
Try it with:

```
"INSERT INTO pumpl2 (price, value, description) VALUES ('".$price."', '".$value."', '".$description."')"
```

Besides that, do not use the $_POST values to enter them directly into the database. Search for SQL Injection on this one. Use mysql_real_escape_string on the $_POST data first, or even better use prepared statements.

Comment: Specifying the values is not necessary if you're inserting a value for every column, and in the correct order. However, it *is* good practice to specify them. EDIT: ah right, the OP wasn't inserting into all columns.

Answer (score 0):

It could be several reasons.

Try

```
echo "Errormessage: ".$db->error;
```

to get more details, why the Insert didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Your table is called `products` not `pumpl2`. Furthermore you should do:

```
insert into product (price, value, description) values ( ...
```